# Cannot return a VBA dictionary to another function

Tags: excel, dictionary, return-value, vba

I'm trying to return a dictionary from a function in VBA.  A dictionary is the best way to go about this, as I am returning a series of arrays (the number of which can vary) and each array has a natural name (the modified input point).  The Code is below.  VBA dies on the last line, where I am trying to do my return value.  I have tried defining the function as an object, as nothing, and the failure is the same.  Would appreciate any ideas.

Note this function will never be called from the sheet.  The overall code is simulating derivatives portfolio risk (hence each entry in the dictionary is bumped market data to allow for scenario valuations to generate risk).  This particular model is simple enough the dictionary is not required, but as soon as I move to more complex models the market data will be too hard to massage without dictionaries.

Thank you for the help,

```
Public Function curveRiskEngine(tenors, rates, ratetype, Optional interptype 
= "linear", Optional biDirectional = True) As Object

If TypeName(tenors) = "Range" Then
    tenors = ConvertRangeTo1DArray(tenors)
End If
If TypeName(rates) = "Range" Then
    rates = ConvertRangeTo1DArray(rates)
End If
If TypeName(ratetype) = "Range" Then
    ratetype = ConvertRangeTo1DArray(ratetype)
End If
bumpsize = 0.0001
basecurve = swapcurvebuilder(tenors, rates, ratetype, False, False, 
interptype)

Dim RE As Scripting.Dictionary
Set RE = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim UpBumps As Scripting.Dictionary
Set UpBumps = New Scripting.Dictionary
If biDirectional Then
    Dim DownBumps As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DownBumps = New Scripting.Dictionary
End If

RE.Add "BaseCurve", basecurve

For i = 1 To UBound(tenors)
    bmprates = rates
    bmprates(i) = rates(i) + 0.0001
    UpBumps.Add tenors(i), swapcurvebuilder(tenors, bmprates, ratetype, 
False, True, interptype)
    If biDirectional Then
        bmprates(i) = rates(i) - 0.0001
        DownBumps.Add tenors(i), swapcurvebuilder(tenors, bmprates, ratetype, 
False, True, interptype)
    End If

Next

RE.Add "UpBumps", UpBumps
If biDirectional Then
    RE.Add "DownBumps", DownBumps
End If


curveRiskEngine = RE



End Function
```

Comment: I figured this out, it seems you need to use the "Set" command at the end of the code when setting the function to the dictionary and also use Set in the invocation.  I would love it if anyone could elucidate why this is.

Comment: You have to use `Set` when you are assigning objects to variables. This is just vba syntax and that's the way it is.

Comment: I suggest you also declare the function `CurveRiskEngine(...) As Scripting.Dictionary` to gain the type checking at the invocation.

Comment: @SSonni - see here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/240688/why-does-vba-vbscript-require-set-prefix

Comment: @Tim Williams. Thanks.  Very helpful primer on why the set is required.  Is this going to be true of all objects gained access to through vba references?  I ask because I’ve always thought of sheets and ranges as objects as well, but haven’t used “set” on those I don’t think.

Comment: Yes, it's true for all object-type references, whether custom classes or "built-in" objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `Set` for objects (more complex data types).

While I'm not a VBA expert, I suspect this is because you're calling a set method of the object, rather than writing to the memory it occupies.

Comment: Here's a useful explainer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/240688/why-does-vba-vbscript-require-set-prefix